How to get MessagePack working with SIgnalR hub
When I try to call my SignalR hub's Chat method I get the error - Error: Failed to invoke 'Chat' due to an error on the server. InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked.  If I remove the .withHubProtocol(new signalR.protocols.msgpack.MessagePackHubProtocol()) in the javascript call it works fine.
Here's the code.
(Model)
[MessagePackObject]
public class AiChatRequestViewModel
{
    public AiChatRequestViewModel(){}
    
    [Key(0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key(1)]
    public string UserPrompt { get; set; }
    [Key(2)]
    public int Samples { get; set; } = 4000;
    [Key(3)]
    public string DocumentText { get; set; }
    [Key(4)]
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; } = 0.0m;
    [Key(5)]
    public List<AiChatMessage> PreviousMessages { get; set; } = new List<AiChatMessage>();
    [IgnoreMember]
    public string AIPrompt => $@"Human: {UserPrompt} {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DocumentText) ? string.Empty : "\n\nDocument: " + DocumentText)} \n\nAssistant:";
}

[MessagePackObject]
public class AiChatMessage
{
    [Key(0)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Key(1)]
    public AiUserRole Role { get; set; } = AiUserRole.User;
    [Key(2)]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public enum AiUserRole
{
    User,
    Assistant
}

(Javascript)
const askQuestion = async () => {
        
    var question = document.getElementById(selectors.questionInput).value;
    if (question.trim().length === 0){
        toastr.error("Please enter a question first.");
        return;
    }
    
    let aiAnswer = "";
    let chatData = {
        UserId: parseInt(userId),
        UserPrompt : question,
        Samples: 256,
        DocumentText: "",
        Temperature: 0.0,
        PreviousMessages: chatHistory
    };
    
    try {
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/chatHub")
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .withHubProtocol(new signalR.protocols.msgpack.MessagePackHubProtocol())
            .build();

        await connection.start();

        connection.stream("Chat", chatData)
            .subscribe({
                next: (item) => {
                    if (item !== null)
                    {
                        aiAnswer += item;
                        document.getElementById(selectors.aiResponseDiv).innerHTML += item.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
                    }
                },
                complete: () => {
                    chatHistory.push({
                        Message: question,
                        EventDate: new Date(),
                        Role: 0
                    });
                    chatHistory.push({
                        Message: aiAnswer,
                        EventDate: new Date(),
                        Role: 1
                    });
                    connection.stop().then(() => {
                            console.log("connection closed");
                        }
                    );
                },
                error: (err) => {
                    toastr.error(err);
                },
            });
    }catch(exc){
        toastr.error(exc);
    }
}

(Server Hub)
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Chat(AiChatRequestViewModel requestViewModel)
{
    var client = new AnthropicClient()
    {
        Auth = new APIAuthentication(AwsSecretsManager.AnthropicApiKey)
    };
    
    var messages = new List<Message>();
    
    foreach (var message in requestViewModel.PreviousMessages)
    {
        messages.Add(new Message()
        {
            Role = message.Role == AiUserRole.User ? RoleType.User : RoleType.Assistant,
            Content = new List<ContentBase>()
            {
                new TextContent()
                {
                    Text = message.Message
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    messages.Add(new Message()
    {
        Role = RoleType.User,
        Content = new List<ContentBase>()
        {
            new TextContent()
            {
                Text = requestViewModel.AIPrompt
            }
        }
    });
    var parameters = new MessageParameters()
    {
        Messages = messages,
        MaxTokens = requestViewModel.Samples,
        Model = AnthropicModels.Claude3Haiku,
        Stream = true,
        Temperature = requestViewModel.Temperature,
    };
    
    var outputs = new List<MessageResponse>();
    await foreach (var res in client.Messages.StreamClaudeMessageAsync(parameters))
    {
        if (res.Delta != null)
        {
            yield return res.Delta.Text;
        }

        outputs.Add(res);
    }
}

The program.cs file does include the call to AddMessagePackProtocol
(Program.cs)
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options => 
{ 
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; 
}).AddMessagePackProtocol();


I guess, the AiUserRole enum is the problem. By default, the signal-r messagepack fortmatter will serialize enum values as strings ("User", "Assistant"). On the client side you use numbers (Role: 0) that server side formatter will not understand.
I had a similar problem and solved it with a custom resolver, that serializes enums as numbers:
Signal-R registration:
    services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerOptions = options.SerializerOptions.WithResolver(Hub.CustomResolver.Instance);
    });

Implementation of the CustomResolver:
public class CustomResolver : IFormatterResolver
{
    public static readonly IFormatterResolver Instance = new CustomResolver();

    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<IFormatterResolver> Resolvers = new IFormatterResolver[]
    {
        DynamicEnumResolver.Instance,
        ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance,
    };

    public IMessagePackFormatter<T>? GetFormatter<T>()
    {
        return Cache<T>.Formatter;
    }

    private static class Cache<T>
    {
        public static readonly IMessagePackFormatter<T>? Formatter = ResolveFormatter();

        private static IMessagePackFormatter<T>? ResolveFormatter()
        {
            foreach (var resolver in Resolvers)
            {
                var formatter = resolver.GetFormatter<T>();
                if (formatter != null)
                {
                    return formatter;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

